# How to get a secured credit card in USA as foreigner?

Tags: credit

I am thinking to move to USA and understand that i would ideally need a good credit history to get  a decent mortgage loan. There are some answers regarding getting a "Secured Credit Card". Can i know how this work because this is the first time i heard of it. Does it work like a debit card where i spend only the money that i have put in the bank?

There was a previous posting, a few years ago, on a specific bank to use for this purpose, is that advice still valid? or can i use Bank of America for the above purpose?

I do not currently hold any American Express cards therefore cannot leverage on the possibility of backdating the credit history as proposed in some of the answers.

Lastly, is 6 months still the period required for a good credit history buildup before i can apply for mortgage loan?

Thank you very much

Comment: For most of your questions, I think you just want to review [the secured-credit-card questions on the Money StackExchange site](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secured-credit-card) - they have a lot more details there than we'll have on the topic!

Comment: You're probably not going to get a mortgage loan within 6 months anyway--they'll want to see some income history, something you won't have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic; might be better on [SEMoney](https://money.stackexchange.com/) and [as suggested by Gagravarr](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/secured-credit-card)